# Exporting Foreach loop output to MS Excel

Tags: powershell, export-to-excel, hyper-v

Based on [my question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458162/foreach-statement-display-issue) for getting all VM's list, I am trying to export data from a foreach loop to an Excel file.

But it seems to be creating a blank CSV file and not writing anything inside. If I try the query without foreach loop it works fine. Any idea what changes are required here?

```
 $name= get-content C:\monitor\Serverlist\Serverlist.txt
 foreach($nam1 in $name)
 { 
     Write-output $nam1
     Get-VM -computername $nam1 |out-default |Select Name,State,Status,Uptime |  Export-Csv -path "c:\report\VMList.csv" –NoTypeInformation
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you need to hard code what data and where they are to be placed in excel instead of using out-default

Comment: Without using out-default its not giving desired result, since it displays list in incorrect order. Like all server list once and Vm infos at once instead of Server and then Vm info pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973404/powershell-foreach-loop-export-to-new-column-in-csv.  I'd start by learning the basics of `Export-CSV` by using it with `Get-Process` for example.